# Windows Hotkey Interferes with AHK Hotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have an AHK program with a hotkey `#u` but when when I try to launch it using an AHK script, it just opens the Windows Updates page (standard function of Windows + U).

Script 1:

```
#u::
;script here
return
```

Script 2:

```
send, #u
```

How can I prevent Windows hotkey from taking over across scripts?
I even tried running both [with UI Access](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#uac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want another script to be able to see your inputs (as opposed to the OS as is happening right now, you need to change your [SendLevel](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendLevel.htm) on the script that is sending in input.

---

**Example using SendLevel**

```
;Script2
SendLevel, 1
Send, #u
```